# ASP.Net MVC V1.00 Installation Failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tried to install ASP.Net MVC but the install keeps rolling back. I Googled this and followed the advice found but there are no add-ins, have the latest hot-fixes and so forth. Using Vista, .NET 3.5 SP1 and VS2008. Even downloaded the MS Web Platform installer and this installed everything except ASP.Net MVC!

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using VS2008 SP1 too? Just .NET 3.5 SP1 is not enough iirc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this?

- [Haacked - Known Installation Issues With ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/12/03/known-installation-issues-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx)